# Rank-Preserving Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I am wondering if there exist transformations that preserve the rank of a matrix.

Specifically, if $A$ is a rank $k$ positive semi-definite matrix (PSD), can we exhibit a transformation $T$ such that $T(A)$ has rank $k$, and possibly is also PSD.

Moreover, is there a non-linear (convex?) function $f$ such that $B : B_{ij}=f(A_{ij})$ is PSD and of rank $k$ ?

Comment: The transpose springs to mind.

Comment: Are there any other properties besides preservation of rank? Should $T$ be linear? Should it preserve positive semi-definiteness?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If possible, $T$ should also preserve positive semi-definiteness ! ( I've edited the question)

Comment: A very simple linear function that works is $T(A) = P^*AP$, where $P$ is a square invertible matrix of the same size as $A$.

Comment: For $p > 1$, $T(A) = A^2$ will be strictly convex (I think!), preserve rank, and map PSD to PSD.

Comment: If we take $f(x) = e^x$, then taking $B_{ij} = f(A_{ij})$ will also be PSD, but I don't know if the rank is maintained.

Comment: Indeed the matrix power preserves PSD and rank, as can be proved by computing it from the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$. Though the element-wise exponential does not preserve the rank (why?).

Answer (score 2):

$T(A)=CA$ or $T(A)=AC$ for any fixed square invertible matrix $C$, with dimensions compatible with the dimensions of $A$.

In particular when $C=cI=diag(c,...,c)$, $T(A)$ is $cA$ ($c$ assumed nonzero).

---

For your second question, there is a partial answer for full rank PSD matrices, i.e., PD matrices: take $f(x)=x^2$ because  the Hadamard product of two PD matrices (here we take twice the same matrix) is still a PD matrix by Schur product theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited the question to a more constrained/specific case. Any hints ?

Comment: See the (partial) answer I have added to my text.

Comment: Indeed every analytic function all of whose coefficients are positive will preserve PSD when applied element-wise. But I don't know if there is a characterization for the functions that preserve both PSD and rank !